# Update where the read file starts MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to code a RLE for bitmaps in MIPS. I'm having problems with the fact that I only discover the file size after reading the file itself and I can't seem to figure out how to read from the middle of the file, to make it recursive.

For example: I discover the file has X bytes from the file header which I read knowing that it has 54 bytes. But then I wanted to jump the first 1078 bytes and read from word to word (4 bytes, 32 bits), or at least be able to create variable .space to put the file in memory.

```
    li $v0, 14          # read from file
    move $a0, $s0           # fd of file to be compressed
    la $a1, header
    li $a2, 54
    syscall

    bne $v0, 54, Erro2      # Test

    lw $s2, header+2        #size of file in bytes
    lw $s3, header+10       #offset of pixel array
```

What I need is to be able to read the pixel array to compress it. But I can figure out how the file descriptor works, if its possible to move its pointer or at least create a .data after que .text already started.

I'm using MARS4_5

Comment: I suggest that you get yourself [a list of syscalls available in MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html). As far as I can tell there's no `seek` syscall. However, there's `sbrk` for allocating memory on the heap.